# SQL: Agregate function for user defined type

Tags: sql, function, aggregate, defined

I have user defined type:

```
create type indeks as integer
```

And question for my exam says: "Define aggregate function max for type indeks"

```
create function max(indeks)
returns indeks
source sysibm.max(integer);
```

Can you help me understand this? Because I know this is some elementary stuff.

```
create function max(indeks) 
returns indeks
```

These two lines are OK, I'm creating function and return type is also indeks.

```
source sysibm.max(integer);
```

But this is what I don't understand. I have no idea what is this line for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which dmbs? (or you'll get an ANSI SQL answer, which may or may not help you...)

Comment: I'm using DB2 if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema name `SYSIBM` is used for built-in data types and built-in functions. The function source from the `SYSIBM.MAX` catalog table is merged into the statement.
The built-in functions cannot simply
be applied to User Defined Types. If they are
required, then UDFs-based on the desired built-in functions must be generated. It means that you need to put this statement there

```
source sysibm.max(integer);
```